# recursion- find the biggest worm in matrix

Tags: java, recursion

i have the following question:
for a nXn matrix, we will define a "worm" at the size of k which is a series of adjacent cells with consecutive numbers. adjacent cell is the cell from the right\left\up\down of the current cell ( not diagonal).
i need to write a recursive function which return the longest worm in array 
for instance: in matrix:

```
{{3,4,5,6},
 {5,6,2,7},
 {12,13,14,15},
 {19,18,17,16}};
```

the longest worm is 8 cells. starting from [2][0] and ends at [3][0].

so far i have written the following code:

```
public static int longestWarm(int[][] arr, int row, int col) {
    if (row < 0 || row >= arr.length || col < 0 || col >= arr.length) return 0;
    if (col >= arr.length || row >= arr.length) return 0;

    int sum1 = 1, sum2 = 1, sum3 = 1, sum4 = 1;

    if (row > 0 && arr[row][col] == arr[row - 1][col] - 1)
            sum1 = 1 + longestWarm(arr, row - 1,col);
    else if (row < arr[0].length - 1 && arr[row][col] == arr[row + 1][col] - 1) 
            sum2 = 1 + longestWarm(arr, row + 1, col);
    else if (col > 0 && arr[row][col] == arr[row][col - 1] - 1) 
            sum3 = 1 + longestWarm(arr, row, col - 1);
    else if (col < arr[0].length - 1 && arr[row][col] == arr[row][col + 1] - 1) 
            sum4 = 1 + longestWarm(arr, row, col + 1);

    int max1 = Math.max(sum1, sum2);
    int max2 = Math.max(sum3, sum4);

    return Math.max(max1, max2);
}
```

the problem is that i get the first worm that i find in matrix and not the biggest one. my output is 5 and not 8.
please help finding what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I think you want to get rid of the `else`s.  Additionally, at the top level you'll need to invoke the method you presented once for each array element, and take the maximum of those results.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks man its working now i created another method which checks if current count is bigger than maxcount and then returns the max

Answer (score 0):

I used the method is_tail to trim only check worms that start at a cell with neighbors that aren't 1 less than it. If such a neighbor exists, then it is obviously not the tail of the longest worm. From each tail you find the max sized worm that grows from that cell similarly to what you did.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

//a pair of ints, row and col, that indicate a cell in a matrix
class Cell {
    int row;
    int col;

    public Cell(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int get_row() {
        return row;
    }

    public int get_col() {
        return col;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "row: " + row + " col: " + col;
    }
}

// a class to hold the matrix data and methods
// so that every call doesnt require passing the pointer m
class Matrix {
    // m used for the matrix so that i dont have to type matrix repeatedly
    int[][] m;
    int height;
    int width;

    public Matrix(int[][] m) {
        this.m = m;
        height = m.length;
        width = m[0].length;
    }

    public int get_height() {
        return height;
    }

    public int get_width() {
        return width;
    }

    // checks if the cell at row,col is a tail
    // a tail is a cell with 0 neighbors that are 1 less than its value
    public boolean is_tail(int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= m.length || col < 0 || col >= m[0].length)
            return false;

        int curVal = m[row][col]; // Value in the cell being checked

        // check if neighbor is out of bounds, then if it is smaller
        if (row - 1 >= 0 && m[row - 1][col] == curVal - 1)
            return false;
        if (row + 1 < m.length && m[row + 1][col] == curVal - 1)
            return false;
        if (col - 1 >= 0 && m[row][col - 1] == curVal - 1)
            return false;
        if (col + 1 < m[0].length && m[row][col + 1] == curVal - 1)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<Cell> longestWorm(int row, int col) {
        if (row < 0 || row >= m.length || col < 0 || col >= m[0].length)
            return new ArrayList<Cell>();

        int curVal = m[row][col];
        ArrayList<Cell> longest_path = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        if (row - 1 >= 0 && m[row - 1][col] == curVal + 1) {
            ArrayList<Cell> path_left = longestWorm(row - 1, col);
            if (path_left.size() > longest_path.size())
                longest_path = path_left;
        }

        if (row + 1 < m.length && m[row + 1][col] == curVal + 1) {
            ArrayList<Cell> path_right = longestWorm(row + 1, col);
            if (path_right.size() > longest_path.size())
                longest_path = path_right;
        }

        if (col - 1 >= 0 && m[row][col - 1] == curVal + 1) {
            ArrayList<Cell> path_up = longestWorm(row, col - 1);
            if (path_up.size() > longest_path.size())
                longest_path = path_up;
        }

        if (col + 1 < m[0].length && m[row][col + 1] == curVal + 1) {
            ArrayList<Cell> path_down = longestWorm(row, col + 1);
            if (path_down.size() > longest_path.size())
                longest_path = path_down;
        }

        longest_path.add(new Cell(row, col));
        return longest_path;
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = { { 3, 4, 5, 6 }, { 5, 6, 2, 7 }, { 12, 13, 14, 15 }, { 19, 18, 17, 16 } };

        ArrayList<Cell> longest_worm = new ArrayList<Cell>();

        Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix(matrix);
        for (int i = 0; i < myMatrix.get_height(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myMatrix.get_width(); j++) {
                if (myMatrix.is_tail(i, j)) {
                    ArrayList<Cell> new_worm = myMatrix.longestWorm(i, j);
                    if (new_worm.size() > longest_worm.size()) {
                        longest_worm = new_worm;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = longest_worm.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(longest_worm.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, something i forget to tell is that i cant use loops anywhere just recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine.
Add this.

```
public static int longestWarm(int[][] arr) {
    int len = arr.length;
    int max = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < len; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < len; ++col) {
            int length = longestWarm(arr, row, col);
            if (length > max)
                max = length;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

And try this

```
int[][] arr = {
    {3, 4, 5, 6},
    {5, 6, 2, 7},
    {12, 13, 14, 15},
    {19, 18, 17, 16}};
System.out.println("lngest warm=" + longestWarm(arr));
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, something i forget to tell is that i cant use loops anywhere just recursion

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with...

```
public static int longestWorm(int[][] mat)
{
    return longestWorm(mat, 0, 0);
}

private static int longestWorm(int[][] mat, int row, int col)
{
    if (row == mat.length)
        return 0;

    if (col == mat[row].length)
        return longestWorm(mat, row + 1, 0);

    int max = longestWorm(mat, row, col + 1);

    int tempMax = longestWorm(mat, row, col, mat[row][col] - 1); // to overload...

    return Math.max(tempMax, max);
}

private static int longestWorm(int[][] mat, int row, int col, int prevCell)
{
    if (row < 0 || row == mat.length || col < 0 || col == mat[row].length)
        return 0;

    if (mat[row][col] - prevCell != 1)
        return 0;

    int temp = mat[row][col];
    mat[row][col] = -999;

    int r1 = 1 + longestWorm(mat, row - 1, col, temp); // up
    int r2 = 1 + longestWorm(mat, row + 1, col, temp); // down
    int r3 = 1 + longestWorm(mat, row, col + 1, temp); // right
    int r4 = 1 + longestWorm(mat, row, col - 1, temp); // left

    mat[row][col] = temp;

    return Math.max(Math.max(r1, r2), Math.max(r3, r4));
}
```